# sites-available subfolders and a2ensite?

Tags: apache2, directory, symbolic-link

Due to my job on my localhost I have a lot (think 50+) sites running, these are for about 8 different clients,

I want to organise my sites into subfolders.

I tried putting my sites in subfolders e.g.

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/client1/first-site
>   /etc/apache2/sites-available/client1/second-site
>   /etc/apache2/sites-available/client1/third-site
>   /etc/apache2/sites-available/client2/first-site2
>   /etc/apache2/sites-available/client2/second-site2

But using any combination of:

> a2ensite client1/first-site
>   a2ensite first-site

says the site does not exist.

If I use:

> a2ensite client1

then I can enable/disable the entire directory, but that's not really what I want..

Is this feasible? or will I have to manually create the symlinks? if so is there a function I can use as a replacement for a2ensite that will handle subfolders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. Consider an organization like this:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/00-client0-first-site
/etc/apache2/sites-available/00-client0-second-site
/etc/apache2/sites-available/00-client0-third-site
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-client1-first-site
/etc/apache2/sites-available/01-client1-second-site
```

So you can enable them without creating symlinks manually.

An [useful link](https://debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2) about multiple Virtual Host